# Android: How to get data from both header and body using KSOAP2

Tags: java, android, web-services, soap, ksoap2

After following a few tutorials(pretty much all the Fahrenheit to Celsius tutorial) I am still at a loss as to how to actually obtain the data I require and set up the request properly.
The main issue is getting inside the header and giving it the PartnerID inside `<AccountInfo/>.`

I also need to give it the following parameters in the body of the request:

```
<keyword>string</keyword>
<records>int</records>
<startingRecord>int</startingRecord>
<searchOptions>ID</searchOptions>
```

Can anyone explain how to achieve this?

```
POST /service/searchapi.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: uk.company.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://api.company.com/service/SearchByKeyword"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <CompanyHeader xmlns="http://api.company.com/service">
      <AccountInfo>
        <PartnerID>string</PartnerID>
      </AccountInfo>
    </CompanyHeader>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <SearchByKeyword xmlns="http://api.company.com/service">
      <keyword>string</keyword>
      <records>int</records>
      <startingRecord>int</startingRecord>
      <searchOptions>ID</searchOptions>
    </SearchByKeyword>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Not to discourage you, but android didn't have SOAP support in the past and I can't find anything about it being supported now. There are a bunch of third party libraries that help you do this but SOAP is very performance intense in comparison to JSON and android changes so fast that these libraries seem to have a hard time keeping up. If you're also setting up the webservice then you're better off with JSON and possibly the GSON conversion library in my experience, if you're not then good luck.

Comment: Unfortunately the web service already exists and they have no intention of changing it :/ I have found a few similar request examples but they all have different formatting to the one shown in the question. The header in particular is problematic. Many of the tutorials dont seem to show or explain how its achieved for a more complex example than the temperature converter either so im at a bit of a loss with undersanding it. The previous project involved JSON and I wish this one did too ahaha. Thanks for the response regardless

Comment: Ouch. I messed around with SOAP for about a week a while ago, I recall the main issue being that you need a DTD to interpret the messages properly since it's not RESTful but android natively uses compiled xml, not actual xml so there's no support for adding a DTD to resources in a sensible manner. You'd have to add it to assets, then run a third party library to work with your other third party library to interpret SOAP messages or something convoluted, unmaintainable and performance intensive like that. It would almost be easier to set up another webservice that converts the SOAP to JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a go all you need to do is put in the correct values and then put it inside an AsyncTask or something like that. The first time i did soap i had a similar problem and it took me quite a while to figure it all out but fingers crossed this should work!

```
        Element[] header = new Element[1];
        header[0] = new Element().createElement(NAMESPACE, "CompanyHeader");

        Element accountInfo = new Element().createElement(NAMESPACE, "AccountInfo");
        header[0].addChild(Node.ELEMENT, accountInfo);

        Element apiKey = new Element().createElement(NAMESPACE, "PartnerID");
        apiKey.addChild(Node.TEXT, "String");
        accountInfo.addChild(Node.ELEMENT, apiKey);

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        PropertyInfo keyword =new PropertyInfo();
        keyword.name = "keyword";
        keyword.setValue("string");
        request.addProperty(keyword);

        PropertyInfo records =new PropertyInfo();
        records.name = "records";
        records.setValue(int);
        request.addProperty(records);

        PropertyInfo startingRecord =new PropertyInfo();
        startingRecord.name = "startingRecord";
        startingRecord.setValue(int);
        request.addProperty(startingRecord);

        PropertyInfo searchOptions =new PropertyInfo();
        searchOptions.name = "searchOptions";
        searchOptions.setValue(string);
        request.addProperty(searchOptions);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope
                .VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.implicitTypes = true;
        envelope.setAddAdornments(false);
        envelope.headerOut = header;
        envelope.bodyOut = request;

        HttpTransportSE ht = getHttpTransportSE();

        try {
            ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (envelope.getResponse() != null) {
                    SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
                    Log.e("Results = ", String.valueOf(results));
                }
            } catch (SoapFault e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```